# Why $abs operator give result -1 if I passed -1 to it.?

Tags: mongodb

I just tried to learn $abs aggregation expression from 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/abs/#exp._S_abs

But when I execute this expression { $abs: -1 } it return -1 instead of 1

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why people gave downward point to this question because am new in MongoDB?

Answer (score 2):

This is an aggregate pipeline operator so you have to use within aggregate function not just `{ $abs: -1 }` as you show in your question. you can try this one it should work.

For example:

```
db.getCollection('Employee').aggregate([
   {
     $project: { amount: { $abs: "$negativeOrPositiveAmount" } }
   }
])
```

NB: $negativeOrPositiveAmount need to change by your actual field name or for check can use -1

Comment: But how to execute or use just aggregate operator without using any collection?

Comment: Obviously, you have to use any collection. for test purpose, you can use any collection name that already exists.